# how to edit, edit columns menu of material-react-table v2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table, material-react-table

[image of table and menu I want to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWevU.png)

I want to add some button at the end of the show/hide(pin) menu.

I had gone through documentation but did not found any solution of how to have custom show/hide(pin) menu.

I'm using material-react-table v2.

#material-react-table #react #javascript

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is customize the buttons above the columns menu, you can import and use the MRT_ShowHideColumnsMenuItems component from material react table, which is a component that renders the columns in the list with the toggle switches, but then render your own buttons in the top or bottom of the menu itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).